# ref vs idref attributes in spring bean declaration

Tags: spring

Can someone tell me the difference between

```
<bean id="b1" class="" />

<bean id="" class="">
 <property name="b1" ref="b1" />
</bean>
```

and

```
<bean id="" class="">
 <property name="b1" idref="b1" />
</bean>
```

and which one has to be used when?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> `ref` is used to pass the bean that the ref refers to.
>   `idref` is used to pass the name of the bean (as a `String`) that is referred to.

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=74355

Answer (score 14):

Here is a little more verbose example, suppose you have two beans A and B:

```
<bean class="A" id="a" />

<bean class="B"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="a"/>
        <idref bean="a"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

In this case B would have a constructor that would look like this:

```
public B(A a, String string) {
     string.equals("a"); //true
}
```

So with ref you can reference an object and with idref you just reference the name of the bean

Answer (score 2):

`idref` must point to a real bean. and the format should be `<idref bean=""/>`

Answer (score 0):

id is used to create an instance of Class, idref is used for pointing to name of the bean

Comment: Question is asked to clarify the difference between ref and idref.