# Spring IDREF usage

Tags: spring

I have a spring.xml defined as per below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>
<bean id="triangle" class="org.tutorial.spring.Triangle">
    <property name="pointA">
        <idref bean="pointA"/>
    </property>
    <property name="pointB" ref="pointB"/>
    <property name="pointC" ref="pointC"/>
</bean>
<bean id="pointA" class="org.tutorial.spring.Point">
    <property name="x" value="0"/>
    <property name="y" value="0"/>
</bean>
<bean id="pointB" class="org.tutorial.spring.Point">
    <property name="x" value="100"/>
    <property name="y" value="200"/>
</bean>
<bean id="pointC" class="org.tutorial.spring.Point">
    <property name="x" value="-100"/>
    <property name="y" value="-200"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

The `Point` class is basically a class with 2 private int members. My problem is i'm getting the error on IDREF as per below:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.tutorial.spring.Point' for property 'pointA'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.tutorial.spring.Point] for property 'pointA': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

As far as i understand, the purpose of the IDREF (in the above case) that bean `PointA` exists (error check) for bean triangle. So i did supply the name of bean `PointA`(string) in the IDREF element. Why do i get the above error? 
 Why is it trying to convert a string to Point when i thought it is just checking the existence of a bean (`PointA`) by just supplying its name?

I'm really confused. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ref vs idref attributes in spring bean declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767831/ref-vs-idref-attributes-in-spring-bean-declaration)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`idref` is used to pass the *name (identifier)* of a bean (that is, a String).

`<idref bean="pointA">` is exactly the same as just the string value `pointA`, except that Spring will complain if such a bean is not defined.

See [the Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-idref-element) for details.

To pass the actual bean just use `ref`, exactly as you do for `pointB` and `pointC`.

Comment: In the question, there is a bean with id as "pointA" and it is being referenced in triangle so why is the exception appearing?

Comment: @GauravKumar because the String `"pointA"` is just that - a String - not the Point bean with the identifier `pointA`.

Comment: idref as u say, is used to pass the name(identifier) of a bean. This is exactly whats done in question.                                                       <property name="pointA">
        <idref bean="pointA"/>
</property>      This statement means , inject a bean with id "pointA" in property "pointA" of bean "triangle". As we can see in question, we do have a bean with id "pointA" defined. So i don't think this exception should appear.  I dont understand the reason behind occurence of this exception. If this bean was not defined then it was understandable

Comment: Nope. Once again: `<property name="foo"><idref bean="bar"/></property>` is **not** at all the same as `<property name="foo" ref="bar"/>`. It is the same as `<property name="foo" value="bar"/>`, except that it will fail when there is no bean named "bar". It's all in the docs, really.

Comment: then what is `idref` used for ? what's the purpose of using it ?  I'm kind of messed up seeing that term.

Comment: @Pavan As [praveen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18539137/2506172) illustrates, _idref_ is useful for cases where you need to pass the name of another bean as a string in a property or constructor-arg.

Answer (score 14):

The idref element is simply an error-proof way to pass the id (string value - not a reference) of another bean in the container to a  or  element.

In simple the idref element is used to pass a string value and using the idref tag allows the container to validate at deployment time that the referenced, named bean actually exists.

consider the below example

[image: class FirstBean]

[image: class SecondBean]

[image: Bean definition in the application context]

[image: the calling code for instantiating the beans]

[image: output in the console]

Notice the output in the console when we invoke secondBean.getSecondMessage() the value is firstBean which was set using the idref attribute.

note:
     A common place where the  element brings value is in the configuration of AOP interceptors in a ProxyFactoryBean bean definition. Using  elements when you specify the interceptor names prevents you from misspelling an interceptor id.

Answer (score 1):

By using ‘idref’ tag, you can validate at deployment time that the referenced, named bean actually exists or not.

For Example,

```
<bean id="paulo" class="com.sample.pojo.Author">
    <property name="firstName" value="Paulo" />
    <property name="lastName" value="Coelho" />
    <property name="dateOfBirth" value="24 August 1947" />
    <property name="country" value="India" />
</bean>
```

If you define your validator bean like below, Spring validates the beans with ids osho and Paulo at deployment time. If any bean not found in the configuration file, then spring throws BeanDefinitionStoreException.

```
<bean id="validatorBean" class="com.sample.test.BeansValidator">
    <property name="author1">
        <idref bean="osho" />
    </property>

    <property name="author2">
        <idref bean="paulo" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Following is the complete working application.

```
package com.sample.pojo;

public class Author {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String dateOfBirth;
    private String country;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("Author [firstName=").append(firstName).append(", lastName=").append(lastName)
                .append(", dateOfBirth=").append(dateOfBirth).append(", country=").append(country).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

BeansValidator.java

```
package com.sample.test;

    public class BeansValidator {
        private String author1;
        private String author2;

        public String getAuthor1() {
            return author1;
        }

        public void setAuthor1(String author1) {
            this.author1 = author1;
        }

        public String getAuthor2() {
            return author2;
        }

        public void setAuthor2(String author2) {
            this.author2 = author2;
        }

    }
```

**myConfiguration.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <bean id="osho" class="com.sample.pojo.Author">
        <property name="firstName" value="Osho" />
        <property name="lastName" value="Jain" />
        <property name="dateOfBirth" value="11 December 1931" />
        <property name="country" value="India" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="paulo" class="com.sample.pojo.Author">
        <property name="firstName" value="Paulo" />
        <property name="lastName" value="Coelho" />
        <property name="dateOfBirth" value="24 August 1947" />
        <property name="country" value="India" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="validatorBean" class="com.sample.test.BeansValidator">
        <property name="author1">
            <idref bean="osho" />
        </property>

        <property name="author2">
            <idref bean="paulo" />
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Run HelloWorld.java, you don’t get any exceptions.

```
package com.sample.test;

    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

    public class HelloWorld {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { "myConfiguration.xml" });

            ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();
        }
    }
```

Now update myConfiguration.xml like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


    <bean id="osho" class="com.sample.pojo.Author">
        <property name="firstName" value="Osho" />
        <property name="lastName" value="Jain" />
        <property name="dateOfBirth" value="11 December 1931" />
        <property name="country" value="India" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="paulo" class="com.sample.pojo.Author">
        <property name="firstName" value="Paulo" />
        <property name="lastName" value="Coelho" />
        <property name="dateOfBirth" value="24 August 1947" />
        <property name="country" value="India" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="validatorBean" class="com.sample.test.BeansValidator">
        <property name="author1">
            <idref bean="Krishna" />
        </property>

        <property name="author2">
            <idref bean="paulo" />
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

As you see the configuration file, validatorBean check for the bean with id ‘Krishna’.

```
<bean id="validatorBean" class="com.sample.test.BeansValidator">
        <property name="author1">
            <idref bean="Krishna" />
        </property>

        <property name="author2">
            <idref bean="paulo" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Since the bean with id ‘Krishna’ don’t exists, you will end up in following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validatorBean' defined in class path resource [myConfiguration.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean name 'Krishna' in bean reference for bean property 'author1'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at com.sample.test.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit perplex I must say. In the example you provide praveen it will work because the attribute in your class is of type String but in the example of yapkm01 the attribut is of type Point and you will get the exception mentioned. In order to be able to use idref it seems that he would have to introduce yet another attribute of type String, here "message", and then the code would look something like this:

```
<property name="message">
    <idref bean="zeroPoint" />
</property>

<property name="pointA" ref="zeroPoint"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not doing anything wrong. You should be using `<ref>` in your code and not `<idref>`. The `<idref>` tag is used to create a String-typed value equal to the ID of the referred bean and is intended for validation purposes.