# Spring id-reference not working as expected

Tags: spring, configuration

I'm working my way through the Spring Framework reference documentation with some very basic application code. So far, I've created an `ApplicationContext` from an XML file and loaded some beans. I believe I understand this process pretty well. I've loaded some basic beans with attributes based on fundamental types and found that straight-forward.

I'm now working on a composite bean with other beans as its attributes. So far, I've been able to set these attributes using a direct reference to a bean and an inner bean. However, when I try to get the `idref` element to work (see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-idref-element) I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.example.BasicBean] for property 'idRef': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Code snippets below:

Application Context XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>
<bean id="id-bean" class="com.example.BasicBean" scope="singleton">
   <property name="value" value="31"/>
</bean>
<bean id="ref-bean" class="com.example.BasicBean" scope="singleton">
  <property name="value" value="37"/>
</bean>
<bean id="cb" class="com.example.CompositeBean" scope="singleton">
  <property name="id" ref="id-bean"/>   <!-- works -->
  <property name="inner">               <!-- works -->
    <bean class="com.example.BasicBean">
      <property name="value" value="43"/>
    </bean>
  </property>
  <property name="idRef">               <!-- exception thrown -->
    <idref bean="ref-bean"/>
  </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Java App Code

```
public void main()
{
  context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
  CompositeBean cb = context.getBean("cb", CompositeBean.class);
}
```

Java Bean Code

```
public class CompositeBean
{
  private BasicBean id;
  private BasicBean idRef;
  private BasicBean inner;
  // Default constructor exists
  // Setters, getters for each attribute exist
  ...
}

public class BasicBean
{
  private int value;
  // Default constructor exists
  // Setters, getters for each attribute exist
  ...
}
```

Version info: I'm using Eclipse IDE (Kepler), Maven 3.1, Java 7 (1.7.45), Spring 3.2.4

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: idref is not meant for that.

Check the first answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607142/spring-idref-usage][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607142/spring-idref-usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Farid for pointing out that I was mis-using the `idref` attribute in this instance. As the Spring doco points out (which I'd read several times and still missed this) it's designed for passing the *id* of a bean around a container and not the actual bean. So, stick to the first two means above (ref and inner bean) for passing a bean around.