# idref tag is not working in spring

Tags: java, spring

I use idref tag to reference another bean, but spring framework thrown a type convertion error, please see my spring.xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id = "triangle" class="org.dxc.javatechnology.Triangle">
        <property name="type" value="Test Value Injection"></property>
        <property name = "c">
            <idref bean= "cycle"/>
        </property>
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="Test Name"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index = "1" value="20"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="cycle" class = "org.dxc.javatechnology.Cycle">
        <property name = "radir" value = "5" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Triangle.java:

```
package org.dxc.javatechnology;

public class Triangle {
    private String type;
    private Cycle c;
    private String name;
    private int height;

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    public Triangle(){}
    public Triangle(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Triangle(String name,int height)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Cycle getC() {
        return c;
    }
    public void setC(Cycle c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public void draw(){
        System.out.println(getType() + " Triangle drawn");
    }
}
```

Cycle.java

```
package org.dxc.javatechnology;

public class Cycle {
    private int radir;

    public int getRadir() {
        return radir;
    }

    public void setRadir(int radir) {
        this.radir = radir;
    }
}
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ConfigurationFiles/spring.xml");
    Triangle triangle  = (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");
    triangle.draw();
    System.out.println(triangle.getC().getRadir());
    System.out.println(triangle.getName());
    System.out.println(triangle.getHeight());
}
```

the error is as below:

```
Apr 08, 2017 11:16:03 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@497470ed: startup date [Sat Apr 08 11:16:03 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 08, 2017 11:16:03 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ConfigurationFiles/spring.xml]
Apr 08, 2017 11:16:03 AM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'triangle' defined in class path resource [ConfigurationFiles/spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.dxc.javatechnology.Cycle' for property 'c'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.dxc.javatechnology.Cycle' for property 'c': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'triangle' defined in class path resource [ConfigurationFiles/spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.dxc.javatechnology.Cycle' for property 'c'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.dxc.javatechnology.Cycle' for property 'c': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.dxc.javatechnology.DrwaingApp.test3(DrwaingApp.java:32)
    at org.dxc.javatechnology.DrwaingApp.main(DrwaingApp.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.dxc.javatechnology.Cycle' for property 'c'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.dxc.javatechnology.Cycle' for property 'c': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:605)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:617)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1577)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1536)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.dxc.javatechnology.Cycle' for property 'c': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:590)
    ... 18 more
```

I don't know what's the problem, can anyone help me?

Comment: This is expected behavior. This question may be a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607142/spring-idref-usage.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `idref` it's just `ref`:

```
<property name = "c" ref = "cycle"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

"idref" is completely different from "ref" . It is easy to get confused . I thought this is best explained with an example rather than lines and lines of text .

Consider any two classes with ONLY String as properties { NOT REFERENCES}

```
package com.imran.beanwrapper;

public class IdrefOne {

String first;

public String getFirst() {
    return first;
}

public void setFirst(String first) {
    this.first = first;
}
```

}

```
package com.imran.beanwrapper;

public class IdrefTwo {

String second;

public String getSecond() {
    return second;
}

public void setSecond(String second) {
    this.second = second;
}

}
```

xml:

```
<bean id="one" 
class="com.imran.beanwrapper.IdrefOne">
<property name="first" value="hai first"/>
</bean>

<bean id="two" 
class="com.imran.beanwrapper.IdrefTwo">

<property name="second">
<idref bean="one"/>
</property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

---

```
Main class : 
ApplicationContext context=new 

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
("wrapperTest.xml");
    
IdrefOne 
one=context.getBean("one",IdrefOne.class);
    
IdrefTwo 
two=context.getBean("two",IdrefTwo.class);
    
System.out.println(one.getFirst());
System.out.println(two.getSecond());
```

ouput:

hai first

one

---

Did u notice the output of System.out.println(two.getSecond()) ?

one
which is equal to "id value" of the first bean namely com.imran.beanwrapper.IdrefOne ( Not equal to bean itself or string value of dependency of bean. Avoid confusion)

Note that the both classes (IdrefOne , IdrefTwo )must have string as dependencies not Object subclasses as dependencies i.e, reference classes

If in the above code if our pojo classes have Object subclasses as dependencies the above code will end up with an exception

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.imran.beanwrapper.IdrefOne' for property '': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

So, we can conclude for the above code setup with strings as dependencies for the pojo classes IdrefOne , IdrefTwo. The code

```
<property name="second">
<idref bean="one"/>
</property>
```

produces same results as the following code

```
<property name="second" value="one">
</property>
```

With first XML snippet using 'idref' , if a bean named "one" is not found in the container an exception is thrown. With second xml snippet , u can give Any String value as u want to 'value' attribute .
So the question is why not use the regular "value" which is generally used and avoid all the this confusion ?

Answer is in the spring documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-idref-element

The first form is preferable to the second, because using the 'idref' tag allows the container to validate at deployment time that the referenced, named bean actually exists. In the second variation, no validation is performed on the value that is passed to the targetName property of the client bean. Typos are only discovered (with most likely fatal results) when the client bean is actually instantiated. If the client bean is a prototype bean, this typo and the resulting exception may only be discovered long after the container is deployed.

A common place (at least in versions earlier than Spring 2.0) where the 'idref' element brings value is in the configuration of AOP interceptors in a ProxyFactoryBean bean definition. Using 'idref' elements when you specify the interceptor names prevents you from misspelling an interceptor id.