# Spring idref not working as I thought

Tags: java, xml, spring

Given the following code of spring.xml, it seens that something is wrong with idref ... please explain what

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean id="triangle" class="org.koushik.javabrains.Triangle">

        <property name="pointA">
            <idref bean="zeroPoint"/>
        </property>

        <property name="pointB">
            <bean class="org.koushik.javabrains.Point">
                <property name="x" value="-20" />
                <property name="y" value="0" />
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="pointC">
            <bean class="org.koushik.javabrains.Point">
                <property name="x" value="20" />
                <property name="y" value="0" />
            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="zeroPoint" class="org.koushik.javabrains.Point">
        <property name="x" value="0" />
        <property name="y" value="0" />
    </bean>
    <alias name="triangle" alias="triangle-alias" />
    <alias name="triangle" alias="triunghi" />
</beans>
```

From some source I found that:

```
<property name="pointD">
<idref bean="squarePointD"/>
</property>
```

is equals to the below one

```
<property name="pointD">
<value>squarePointD</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Thats how idref works. idref is used to set the value of a bean property to a bean id of another bean in the context. It is not used to set the property to the reference of another bean like ref. It is useful in cases where you want Spring to ensure that the value pointed by idref actual refers to an id of an existing bean. If there is no matching bean then an exception id thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`idrefs` can be considered as Strings. idref is used to pass the name of the bean (as a String) that your bean is referring to. Are `PointA, pointD,` etc strings in you class?

Since you seem to be referring to a custom class `org.koushik.javabrains.Point` it may not work. Setter or constructor parameters you are setting/injecting should be Strings when you want to use idref. The container will verify that the bean which is referred to via `idref` actually exists at deployment time. Otherwise it will throw an error.

You can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18539137/668951 and [ref vs idref attributes in spring bean declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767831/ref-vs-idref-attributes-in-spring-bean-declaration) for more details.